# Relative paths in Ant Property are not working

Tags: ant

I'm trying to store a relative path to a file in my ant build.xml like this:

```
<property name="foo" location="somedir/myfile" relative="true"/>
```

According to the Ant [manual for Property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) this is ok syntax, but when running it Ant says:

> property doesn't support the
>   "relative" attribute

I'm using Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on August 13 2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual that came with 1.7.1 distribution does not mention `relative` property.

If you look at the top of [ant manual link](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html), it says 1.8.0RC1.
I guess these are new 1.8.0 attributes of `property` task.
Probably you should report a bug to the ant team to mark `relative` and `basedir` attributes as `Since 1.8.0`

On the other hand if you need a relative path to a `basedir`, just use a `value` attribute of `property` task.

**-- UPDATE**

I've submitted a bug to [ant team](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48609)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if in the location is not specified the root path ('/') which is absolute , it takes relative as default, so the "relative=true" is unnecesary.

> **location**  Sets the property to the absolute filename of the given file. If the value of this attribute is an absolute path, it is left unchanged (with / and \ characters converted to the current platforms conventions). Otherwise it is taken as a path relative to the project's basedir and expanded. (from the documentation)

Comment: But i don't want an absolute path. The ant cvs target requires a relative path to the file being committed.

Comment: perhaps you ommit the base url from where to be relative
 <property name="foo" location="my/file.txt" relative="true" basedir="cvs"/>